# Stricts-Standards Errors on Joomla

Tags: php, ssh, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla 2.5, which I can't upgrade, who print this:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method JURI::base() should not be called statically in /home/fmschass/public_html/plugins/system/JCH_Optimize.php on line 474
```

The php.ini on the server is set on this, and the display_errors is off :

```
E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING
```

In search in `SSH` for `reporting` but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have this problem :

1. Set error_reporting to 0 in `configuration.php`
2. Clear the folder cache `cache/plg_JCH_Optimize/`